# Merging two Ubuntu partitions while keeping the data

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I'm kinda new to Linux. I have installed the latest Ubuntu Gnome LTS a while ago while keeping Windows 10 (dual-booting).

I've uploaded a screenshot of my drives from GParted.

[image: drives]

1. What is the difference between `sda6` and `sda7`? Which one is the primary?
2. How can I merge the two together while keeping my data (`home` folder, I guess).

My goal is to resize (shrink) the total Linux space and add more to Windows.

Answer (score 0):

/dev/sda7 is your primary Ubuntu partition - look at the mount-point! It is / (root).
You do not want to move this partition!

You have 2 gal-partitions one Windows NTFS, and your sda6 ext4 linux partition. The fastest way to move your sda6 files to your root (/ sda7) partition is to create a folder in your home-directory, copy all files from sda6 to this folder, verify that they are there, then dismount sda6 and delete it from Gparted!
Then reboot on a live ISO (we can not make changes to a mounted partition) - start Gparted and extend your ext4 partition into the unclaimed space(former sda6) (sda7 might have an other name after booting the live ISO probably sdb?)
Reboot into Ubuntu and your partition should be 90+GB now (85+ GB from sda6 and 5 unclaimed).
Good luck and happy Ubunting.

Comment: Great, I've successfully unmounted sda6 and made it unallocated space. But it's still under the "extended" section which means that I can't allocate it to the window partition. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Sorry I was under the impression that you wanted to merge SDA7 with SDA6.
I'm not sure that you can unextend part of an extended partition!
This is one of many things that GPT format solves for us, but that craves a totally reformation of the HD.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to use this space is to create a partition in the unallocated space and format this partition with NTFS. Give the partition a drive letter, so you can see the partition in Windows, if you want you can give it a label too.

You may use this partition to move private data from your Windows-partition to this new partition. That will give you more space on your system-partition which you might use for the installation of programs. Your screenshot shows, that there is plenty of space left anyway.

It is always a good idea to have private data separated from your system-partition just for the case of a heavy system failure. Your data on a separated partition will not be affected.

You can access this partition from Ubuntu as well, Ubuntu handles NTFS-file-system flawless.

If you just want to increase your Windows-partition, this will be a much bigger deal. First you would have to move your Ubuntu-partition next to your swap-partition.This is a risky action, this means moving data of an operating system, if something goes wrong Ubuntu is gone.

As second step you would have to resize the extended partition (sda3). After this is done you can resize the Windows-partition.

You think, we are done now? We are not! We moved the Ubuntu-partition, so we will get problems booting Ubuntu if we don't adapt the fstab-file and Grub-boot-loader... What kind of action this is, you can read [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MovingLinuxPartition).

Why we do easy things when we can have it difficult ?

Your decision !